# MVC 6 and adding open source HTML5 Templates, how does controller serve content?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I just downloaded and installed MVC 6, created a project which looks like this:

[image]

The project runs fine.  Now I want to add this project to the solution.

https://github.com/jiji262/Bootstrap_Metro_Dashboard

I've cloned the libarary and added it to the wwwroot folder as shown here:

[image]

Now I want to serve up the index.html from the Home controller (which I can create just for Dashboard requests)

If I right click on the ActionMethod named Dashboard (created in HomeController), it has no option to create view.  Ok... new change to me...

[image: Right Click Controller no add View]

If I go to the views folder and right click and AddView, I get this:

[image: AddView]

The Add button not enabled until I *add a model and the dbcontext* which there is none...

This means I should just copy an exiting or go ahead and create and rip out the plumbing...  This gives me this:

[image]

Question: How do I serve the content from the Dashboard ActionMethod in the HomeController for the index.html of the Bootstrap_Metro_Dashboard-master directory in the WWWRootFolder?  I'm thinking the index.html is already there I shouldn't need a MVC view, rather I should be able to return the Index.html directly right?

Comment: Create a partial view which has the HTML markup you want, and include that in your view.

Comment: Shouldn't need to do that because the index.html already exists.  I simply want to contain that page inside a MVC view similar to a partial view but for static content.